# VueJS Hotel Datepicker: issue in getting selected date via event listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2

I am new to VueJS and trying to implement the [`vue-hotel-datepicker`](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker)
in my project. However, I don't understand how to use the [`checkInChanged`](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker#checkinchanged) event listener.

This is my template code:

```
 <datepicker
     :startDate="startDate"
     :checkInChanged="setCheckinDate()" //probem occurs here
     :maxNights="30"
     :disabledDates="bookedDates"
     :firstDayOfWeek="1"
     :i18n="lang"
     :showYear="true"
    >

  </datepicker>
```

My method:

```
 methods: {
     setCheckinDate() {
       console.log('test');
     }
 }
```

This event fires before I even select a check in date. How should I best implement this and how can I grab the date instance in my `setCheckinDate()` method?

**EDIT**: 
see my [gist](https://gist.github.com/heleneshaikh/455ae994d80a645e295b5b75560d9bcd) for the complete code. I have changed my listener from `:checkInChanged` to `@checkInChanged` as suggested in the comments, but the event does not get fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkInChanged` is an event not a prop so you should use `v-on:check-in-changed` or `@check-in-changed` instead of `:checkInChanged` and remove the `()` from the handler :

```
    <datepicker
        :startDate="startDate"
        @check-in-changed="setCheckinDate"
         ...
```

and your method should be like :

```
   methods: {
      setCheckinDate(newDate) {
        console.log(newDate);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried your solution with no success and I created a gist (see my edited question)

Comment: Try `@check-in-changed`.

Comment: @MatJ both syntaxes are correct, but i prefer that you suggested

Comment: Weirdly enough, it only works with `@check-in-changed` and not with the camelcase `@checkInChanged`...

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim html attributes are case-insensitive, so Vue explicitly requests we use [hyphenated syntax when camelcase is involved](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case).