# How can I use $emit with Vue.js when using the Vue CLI project setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, vuejs2

Thank you for any help you can provide. Does anyone know how one can use the $emit method within Vue.js to send data up-chain to a global method? I had no problems getting this to work on a very basic example with Vue.js. However, once setting up my project using Vue CLI, with the more advanced folder structure, my method does not seem to be registering properly.

In my `Register.vue` component, I register a new user, and upon doing so want to send the new user up-stream to update my global scope:

```
this.$emit("login-user", newUser);
```

My component is registered as follows:

```
<Register msg="Otherwise, go ahead and register here:" :login-user="loginNewUser"/>
```

Where `:login-user` references the global method: `loginNewUser()`.

The `loginNewUser()` method is setup as follows within `main.js`:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  methods: {
    loginNewUser(user) {
      console.log(user);
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

Is my method in the wrong place? How can I send data up stream from my component to my global scope, when using the Vue CLI `create` project heirarchy? This method was working previously, however my application was setup slightly different and I may be overlooking something very important.

### More Info

- You can see the full repo for this project if you wish at: https://github.com/twknab/viaRV_vue_cli_project
- Within `src/components/Register.vue`, [on line 76](https://github.com/twknab/viaRV_vue_cli_project/blob/85dd63d5323d66405148b29dfbc8e5424088eaff/src/components/Register.vue#L76) is where I try and make my `$emit` call to `main.js` and my `loginNewUser()` method [on line 17](https://github.com/twknab/viaRV_vue_cli_project/blob/85dd63d5323d66405148b29dfbc8e5424088eaff/src/main.js#L17.), to which I receive the error message:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "loginNewUser" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Thank you so greatly for your time and for reading.

Comment: try `@login-user="loginNewUser"` and look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54005317/8172857)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is showing because the `loginNewUser` is being referenced in the `Home` component:

`<Register msg="Otherwise, go ahead and register here:" @login-user="loginNewUser"/>`

However **`loginNewUser` is not defined in the `Home` component but in your `main.js`** file which is three levels up in the component hierarchy: `main.js > App.vue > Home.vue`

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  methods: {
    loginNewUser(user) {
      // existing code here
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

---

### **Solution #1**

To solve this, you have to pass the event handler from your `main.js` to your `Home` component which involves 3 steps.

**First**, pass the event handler to `App.vue` by modifying your `render` function in `main.js` from:

`render: h => h(App)`

to this:

```
render: function(createElement) {
  return createElement(App, {
    on: {
      loginNewUser: this.loginNewUser
    }
  })
}
```

> `h` is a more generalized version of `createElement` so basically, they're the same.

> [`createElement`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments)
> accepts several arguments and we will use the `second` argument which
> is a data object to pass `event` handlers to the rendered component.

**Second**, in your `App` component, define `loginNewUser` and pass the reference to the `router-view`.

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    loginNewUser() {
      this.$emit('loginNewUser');
    }
  }
}
```

```
<router-view @login-new-user="loginNewUser"></router-view>
```

**Third**, define `loginNewUser` in your `Home.vue` component.

```
export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    Login,
    Register
  },
  methods: {
    loginNewUser() {
      this.$emit('loginNewUser');
    }
  }
};
```

**Lastly**, in your current code, don't forget to change `:login-user` to `@login-user`.

---

### **Solution #2**

If you are using [`Vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/) or is planning to, instead of passing your event handler from top to bottom, you can use `actions` which you can call anywhere in your components.

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough and thoughtful answer! I ended up moving my global methods to my `App` component (not in `main.js`) and now totally better understand what you mean. I am now emitting from my `Register` component > `Home` component` > (emitting again) to my `App` where my methods and global data is stored. Thank you so much for helping me understand this concept better! Would give you more +1's if I could for your thoroughness and detail, totally guided me towards the correct understanding! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm learning as well by sharing so it's win-win.:)